# How to get focus for selected values when multiselect combo is used

Tags: javascript

I'm using a multiselect combobox, i select few values from the combobox and save the selected values to db. when i reopen the page, i need the focus to be placed on the values which was selected and saved.

```
function getSelectedValues() {
    var from = document.getElementById("309127");
    var to;
    var v = from.options.length;
    var selectedValues = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        if (from.options[i] && from.options[i].selected) {
            var CVal = from.options[i].value;
            var CText = from.options[i].text;

            if (selectedValues == "") {
                selectedValues = CVal;
            }
            else {
                selectedValues = selectedValues + "~" + CVal;
            }

        }
    }
    return selectedValues;

}
```

this is the javascript function i used to save the selected values in db.
can anybody help me out on how to get the focus back on selected items ?
thank you

Comment: u mean all selected option should stay selected as it was before saving right?

Comment: yes tushar, i wanted in that way only

Comment: what is server side scripting jsp/php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the focus with javascript you can use

```
document.getElementById("309127").focus();
```

For your question I'm assuming you send the values to a PHP page or something similar to update the database. If so your problem will be getting the selected values when you return to your page. Two suggestions:

- Use ajax to update the database so you dont need to exit the page,
- Pass the selected values back to your page through GET or similar and set the focus on page load.

EDIT: -------------

For example if you pass the values through GET like (www.example.com?param1=three)

You can use javascript to select that value on load:

```
<html>
<body onload="load()">
<select id="example">
    <option value="one"> one </option>
    <option value="two"> two </option>
    <option value="three"> three </option>
</select>
</body>

<script>
function load(){
    var param1 = getParameterByName("param1");
    var selected = document.getElementById('example');
    var opts = selected.options.length;
    for (var i=0; i<opts; i++){
    if (selected.options[i].value == param1){
        selected.options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
}
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i want to focus on the selected values after save is completed.

Comment: How are you saving in the db?

Comment: Ok struts supports AJAX, are you using ajax? Or after you save the page just return to it reloading it? If so you have to pass to the page the values that were selected. For example using GET: (http://example.com?param1=val1&param2=val2) Where val is the CVal. Then using javascript you could search for the values in the combobox that had those values and focus them using .focus()

Comment: using dyna form, i'm able to fetch the selected vaues back from the db on page refresh, but facing problem in focusing. can you explain in more detail if possible. it would of great help

Answer (score 0):

try `var from = document.getElementById("309127");from.focus();`

Comment: i want to focus on selected values, not on the combobox